# Android - Too many new String cause very slow and GC information

Tags: java, android

Each machine has one `myFile` to read. There are tons of elements to be read in `myFile`. Each element has 256 bytes so I declare `recData` as 256 bytes. In `while (bis.read(recData, 0, SIZE_OF_DB_Record) != -1)`, each loop read one element(256bytes) from `myFile` to `recData` and parse the information and store into `tcrDbRecord` variable. The information might be parsed to String, int, or long. So, I also use `ntoh_4bytes` and `ntoh_8bytes` for parsing int and long because `myFile` is received from network.

The point is that all it can work correctly but it costs super-duper long. I find out the reason might be that I use `new String()` too many times. Then, I commit an experiment. If I delete all `new String()` code in the `while loop`, it works super fast. If I add one `new String()` code in `while loop`, it become slow obviously. I guest the problem is caused by using too many `new String()`. Besides, I also get many this kind of GC information

```
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 390820(8MB)
AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 519us total 100.362ms.
```

However, I need to parse these information by ASCII code. Please help me resolve it.

```
File file;
BufferedInputStream bis;
byte[] recData = new byte[256];
byte[] tmpRecDataStr = new byte[256];            
byte[] tmpRecDataLong = new byte[8];
byte[] tmpRecDataInt = new byte[4];
TCR_DB_Record tcrDbRecord = new TCR_DB_Record();

for (int i = 0; i < numMachine; i++) {
    try {
        file = new File(LoginActivity.dataDir + "/" + i, "myFile");
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while (bis.read(recData, 0, 256) != -1) {

            //get date
            System.arraycopy(recData, 0, tmpRecDataLong, 0, 4);
            tcrDbRecord.date = ntoh_8bytes(tmpRecDataLong);

            //get time
            System.arraycopy(recData, 4, tmpRecDataLong, 0, 4);
            tcrDbRecord.time = ntoh_8bytes(tmpRecDataLong);

            //get channel
            System.arraycopy(recData, 8, tmpRecDataInt, 0, 2);
            tcrDbRecord.chanNo = ntoh_4bytes(tmpRecDataInt);

            //get file path
            System.arraycopy(recData, 10, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16);
            tcrDbRecord.filePath = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.filePath = tcrDbRecord.filePath.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get file name
            System.arraycopy(recData, 26, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 14);
            tcrDbRecord.fileName = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 14, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.fileName = tcrDbRecord.fileName.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get file size in byte
            System.arraycopy(recData, 64, tmpRecDataLong, 0, 4);
            tcrDbRecord.fileSize = ntoh_8bytes(tmpRecDataLong);

            //get length of the record in second
            System.arraycopy(recData, 68, tmpRecDataLong, 0, 4);
            tcrDbRecord.second = ntoh_8bytes(tmpRecDataLong);

            //get value
            System.arraycopy(recData, 76, tmpRecDataLong, 0, 4);
            tcrDbRecord.value = ntoh_8bytes(tmpRecDataLong);

            //get case id
            System.arraycopy(recData, 80, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16);
            tcrDbRecord.caseID = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.caseID = tcrDbRecord.caseID.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get comment
            System.arraycopy(recData, 96, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16);
            tcrDbRecord.comment = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 16, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.comment = tcrDbRecord.comment.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get extension
            System.arraycopy(recData, 112, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 24);
            tcrDbRecord.ext = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 24, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.ext = tcrDbRecord.ext.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get agent name
            System.arraycopy(recData, 136, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32);
            tcrDbRecord.name = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.name = tcrDbRecord.name.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get agent id
            System.arraycopy(recData, 168, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 24);
            tcrDbRecord.id = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 24, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.id = tcrDbRecord.id.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get department
            System.arraycopy(recData, 192, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32);
            tcrDbRecord.dep = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.dep = tcrDbRecord.dep.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");

            //get group
            System.arraycopy(recData, 224, tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32);
            tcrDbRecord.group = new String(tmpRecDataStr, 0, 32, "US-ASCII");
            tcrDbRecord.group = tcrDbRecord.group.replaceAll("\\u0000", "");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code of `ntoh_4bytes` and `ntoh_8bytes` are as below but I think it does not matter.

```
int ntoh_4bytes(byte[] b)
{
    return   b[0] & 0xFF |
            (b[1] & 0xFF) << 8 |
            (b[2] & 0xFF) << 16 |
            (b[3] & 0xFF) << 24;
}


long ntoh_8bytes(byte[] b)
{
    return   b[0] & 0xFF |
            (b[1] & 0xFF) << 8 |
            (b[2] & 0xFF) << 16 |
            (b[3] & 0xFF) << 24 |
            (b[4] & 0xFF) << 32 |
            (b[5] & 0xFF) << 40 |
            (b[6] & 0xFF) << 48 |
            (b[7] & 0xFF) << 56;
}
```

Comment: Mostly because you call `replaceAll` method on those, that is not helping. This is a process that will read every character to find the pattern you pass. I would suggest to check this logic, there are many array copy used here too. For more help, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try using one String outside the loop and use that only each time. rather creating new in each iteration.

Comment: PS : Don't forget that an android device is less powerfull than you computer or a server. That the fun of android development, performance ;)

Comment: Doing `Charset ascii = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");` and passing that into your string constructors should help.

Comment: You should parse your file Data and create separate keys for each string and store into Sqlite Database  and Store each String value with key and query only those strings which you want at a time by using predefined keys.And define your keys in to string.xml file

Comment: Thanks, RATHI. How do I use just one String outside the loop? I need to convert byte array to String in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, AxeIH. Your advice can help improve 60% faster.

Comment: Thanks, Ken Y-N. I try your method but don't feel any faster.